# HTTP post request parameters doesn't change default values of Mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

I created two Mongoose schemas and want to test them with Postman. 
When I send a post HTTP request my parameters doesn't change the default value from the AnimalSchema nor does at StorySchema.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var AnimalSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type : String, default: ""},
    audio: {type : String, default: ""},
    image: {type : String, default: ""}
});

mongoose.model('Animal', AnimalSchema);
```

---

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var Animal = mongoose.model('Animal');
var Story = mongoose.model('Story');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/animals', function(req, res, next){
  Animal.find(function(err, animals){
    if(err){
      return next(err);
    }
    res.json(animals);
  });
});

router.post('/animals', function(req, res, next){
  var animal = new Animal(req.body);

  animal.save(function(err,animal){
    if(err){return next(err);}

    res.json(animal);
  });
});

router.get('/stories', function(req, res, next){
  Story.find(function(err, stories){
    if(err){return next(err);}

    res.json(stories);
  });
});

router.post('/stories', function(req, res, next){
  var story = new Story(req.body);

  story.save(function(err, story){
    if(err){return next(err);}

    res.json(story)
  });
});

module.exports = router;

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// connect MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/stuckyToys', function(err,db){
    if (!err){
        console.log('Connected to /stuckyToys!');
    } else{
        console.dir(err); //failed to connect
    }
});

require('./models/Animals');
require('./models/Stories');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

I think I made an error in my app.js file. But not sure where it is.
Anyone knows what I did wrong?

[image: Database content with Robomongo]

[image: Postman 1]

[image: Postman 2]

Comment: Why are you sending the values as request parameters for post request ? Why not send them in a request body ?

Comment: So MongoDB would store those values as an Animal or Story - object

Comment: The problem I think is you are sending them as request parameters and in the code you are taking it off request body which will not have these

Comment: How should I send these parameters then? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong ..

Comment: Try sending them as json from the request body tab in postman

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

```
{*(Model)}.findById(id, function(err, animal) {
                if (err) console.log(err);

                {update new values here in animal with the ones you are receiving in the request}
                animal.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                });
            });
```